# Filtering on all fields of a django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using the `Django Rest Framework` and `Django Filters` to restrict the results of an API call. Is it possible to allow filtering on all models fields that are listed in the serializer?

```
import django_filters
from rest_framework import generics

class ProjectFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'

class ProjectList(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = Project
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
    filter_class = ProjectFilter
```

I know that `fields = '__all__'` does not work, but I am wondering if there is a syntax that can be used here, or if there is a different type of `filter_class` that can be used.

Comment: I thought django-filters was filtering entities, not fields. I might be mistaken, but I suggest you to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand the question, but in your view, can you use `filterset_fields = '__all__'` which means you can filter on all fields in the model like

`https://www.example.com/api/projects/?attr1=x&attr2=y&attr3=z`